# TableRow with two TextView in separate line

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
TextView name = new TextView(this);
                          name.setText(venues.get(j).name);
                          name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                          TextView address = new TextView(this);
                          address.setText(venues.get(j).getFullAddress());
                          address.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                          /* Add Button to row. */
                          tr.addView(name);
                          tr.addView(address);
```

And now it gives me a layout like this:

[image]

I want the TextView to be in separate lines. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use LayoutParams for Views that are going into a TableRow... use TableRow.LayoutParams.

Second (pls tell me if I misunderstood your question), if you want your edittexts to show up on different lines... that means you want them on different rows. In other words, don't put them into the same TableRow. You can put them into separate TableRows or use a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `addr` to another `TableRow`.

```
TextView name = new TextView(this);
TextView addr = new TextView(this);

name.setText("Name");
addr.setText("Addr");

TableRow tableRow1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
TableRow tableRow2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);

tableRow1.addView(name);
tableRow2.addView(addr);
```